# No viable alternative to input - line 25 Jython

Tags: python, jython, apache-nifi

I am creating an ExecuteScript in NiFi so it reads a string and changes the ',' for '#'. But I'm not really fluent in jython and I rarely use the ExecuteScript processor.

```
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        try:

            # Input Flowfile
            input = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

            # Transform Content
            split_csv_line = input.split('"')
            isolate_description = split_csv_line[1]
            description = isolate_description.replace(",","#")
            new_list = split_csv_line[0] + description + split_csv_line[2]

            # Output Flowfile
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(new_list))

flowFile = session.get()

if flowFile != None:
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, TransformCallBack())
    # Transfer flowFile to output relationship
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: there is a standard nifi processor replacetext that does what you are trying to do in a code. if it's not principal I could show how to do this in groovy. to help with jython  you have to provide error/problem.

Comment: You are calling a class `TransformCallBack()` but defined `PyStreamCallback()` . Thats why the error..

Comment: @dagget Thanks for the reply, I'm doing it in a specific part of the string. Regarding groovy, I've never coded in it, but I accept the help !

Comment: @Pushkr Oh wow, how did I missed that .. Thank you for the help